# How to change a python script into an app

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, shebang

I wrote a python cli app which works fine. But every time I want to use it I should use python3 myapp.py which is not the nice and useful way especially because I want to make this app ready to use in pypy so that users might install it using pip.

I want to know the process of changing a python script into a real cli app.

Comment: This is too broad. You need to be more specific. What exactly do you want to achieve, where are you stuck?

Comment: "Pypy" is a python interpreter, "pypi" is the package archive. Also having it on pypi is not a requirement to use pip to install it. There are other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make it available to users via `pip`, you should create the package, build it and upload it to the Python Package Index. There is a tutorial on how to do this in the official docs: **[Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)**

> It will show you how to add the necessary files and structure to create the package, how to build the package, and how to upload it to the Python Package Index.

If you want to convert your python script into an excutable you can use [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). It works on Windows, Linux, and Mac:

> Install PyInstaller from PyPI:
>
> ```
> pip install pyinstaller
> ```
>
> Go to your program’s directory and run:
>
> ```
> pyinstaller yourprogram.py
> ```
>
> This will generate the bundle in a subdirectory called dist.